# How do I disambiguate a property on the global object which is hidden by an object in a namespace?

Tags: typescript

Given the following TypeScript 2.1 code ([snippet](http://codepen.io/brettnieland/pen/mOzMLd)):

```
namespace outerNS {
  export function fnMain() {
    assertTrue(overloadedIdentifierNS.fnToBeCalled() === "intended");
  }
  namespace overloadedIdentifierNS {
    export function fnToBeCalled() {
      return "unintended";
    }
  } 
}

namespace overloadedIdentifierNS {
  export function fnToBeCalled() {
    return "intended";
  } 
}

function assertTrue(v: boolean) {
  if (!v)
    alert("fail!");
}
```

How can I access the global overloadedIdentifier.fnToBeCalled from inside of outerNS?

Comment: You're running that in a browser or node?

Comment: In the browser.

Comment: There's no actual problem here, the two namespace names are different: "overloadedIdentifierNS" and "overloadedIdentifier"

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my namespace identifier.  I have made the necessary edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All global properties in the browser are wrapped up in the `Window` object, so you can do:

```
namespace outerNS {
    export function fnMain() {
        assertTrue(window.overloadedIdentifierNS.fnToBeCalled() === "intended");
    }
    ...
}
...
```

This will work at runtime, but the compiler will complain that:

> Property 'overloadedIdentifierNS' does not exist on type 'Window'

So you can do this instead:

```
assertTrue(window["overloadedIdentifierNS"].fnToBeCalled() === "intended");
```

Or you can augment the `Window` object:

```
interface Window {
    overloadedIdentifierNS: {
        fnToBeCalled: () => string;
    }
}

namespace outerNS {
    export function fnMain() {
        assertTrue(window.overloadedIdentifierNS.fnToBeCalled() === "intended");
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: None of these answers make me happy, but I think they are the best available.

Comment: You can structure your namespace differently so that there won't be a collision, if that's even possible. Otherwise you have no way of avoiding the problem, you'll need to access the namespace from the window object,